# NServiceBus: How to STOP processing of messages

Tags: nservicebus

Is there a way to tell NSB to stop a subscriber from processing messages?  I have a Windows Service and I really need to have Pause/Continue supported.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is stop the Windows Service.  The messages will build up in the queue and to continue, restart the service.